# How to serve static resource in springboot having custom path from Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this resource handler, and I am able to call the static web page located in different location , but I am trying to call from controller class I am not able to get the page

```
@Configuration
public class Static_ResourceHandler implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/system/files/**").addResourceLocations("file:/home/niteshb/Documents/data");
    }
}
```

This is what I am calling

`http://localhost:8080/system/files/test.html`

but how to call it from controller , I was trying something like this but its not working
This is my controller class call ..

```
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getfile() {
        return "test.html";
    }
```

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` and relaunch, also prefix the resource location with `file:`.

Comment: Showing same issue @M.Deinum , I have edited the ques

Comment: Is that a static file or a thymeleaf template?

Comment: Its simple  html file @M.Denium

Answer (score 0):

Create a Get mapping for `/system/files/`, for which you had created the resource handler,
and return the file in the newly created method.

```
@GetMapping("/system/files/")
public String getStaticfile() {
    return "/system/files/test.html";
}
```

Hope that should work.

Comment: Are you sure your path to the resource file is correct?
I generally use the format as:
`file:///home/.../.../data/`
Considering the static file is inside the data folder

Comment: I have ubuntu so file directory path is not as same as windows ..yes the path is ok .. directly accessing http://localhost:8080/system/files/test.html works , I want to call from controller @jay

Comment: @user15895291 Just updated my answer. That should work.